# Why does my canvas spinwheel gets cut off on setting lineWidth?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

This is my draw function for the canvas:

```
 const drawSector = (sector, i) => {
      const ang = arc * i;
      ctx.save();
      // COLOR
      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#ECBA3F";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = sector.color;
      ctx.moveTo(rad, rad);
      ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, ang, ang + arc);
      ctx.lineTo(rad, rad);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      // TEXT

      ctx.translate(rad, rad);
      ctx.rotate(ang + arc / 2);
      ctx.textAlign = "right";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.font = "bold 10px sans-serif";
      ctx.fillText(sector.label, rad - 10, 10);
      //
      ctx.restore();
    };
```

[Here's my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spin-wheel-forked-r5d4mx?file=/src/components/SpinWheel/SpinWheel.js)

As soon as I set a linewidth on the canvas, part of the edges get cutoff seemingly as if the canvas width and height don't take the linewidth into account. How do I fix this?

[image: cut off spin wheel]

Also is there a way I can rotate the text inside the arcs so that they stack rather than just being in a single line. Perhaps something like the below image?

[image: ideal spin wheel]

Comment: Stroke spreads from both sides of the path by half the lineWidth  if you want your cricle's stroke to fit in your canvas you need to make its radius half min(canvas.width, canvas.height) - lineWidth / 2

Comment: Auto fitting text into shapes isn’t easy.  Check https://riptutorial.com/html5-canvas/example/18592/draw-text-paragraphs-into-irregular-shapes for some ideas.

Comment: @Kaiido Could you make it a bit clearer? I don't get what "half min(canvas.width, canvas.height)" means.

Comment: Your canvas has a width and an height, from the screenshots its seems to be squared and thus they might be the same size, but it's not a given, so you may have to find which of the width or the height is the smallest. Then, you can define the radius of your circle to be half of that size, minus half of the lineWidth. Or if you prefer, set the diameter of your circle to that minimal canvas size, minus lineWidth. But to draw your circle, you set the radius of the arc, hence me talking in radius rather than diameter.

Comment: And you'll want to change `ctx.moveTo(rad, rad)` to `ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)` because (rad, rad) wouldn't be the center of your canvas anymore (and do the same in the other places that assumed (rad, rad) is the center).

Comment: @Kaiido Fixed it! Thanks a bunch for your patience and guidance :)